# i am not getting the alert blackberry or other

Tags: javascript

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function getcss(cssfile)
            {
                alert("hi");
                alert(navigator.appName);
            }
            if(navigator.appName("Blackberry"))
            {
                alert("blackberry");
            }
            else
            {
            alert("other");
            }
        </script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>

    <body onload="getcss()">
        <div id="demo">
            Hai Css
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why I am not getting the alert blackberry or other? I have more doubt in that code so I want that clarification for this.

Comment: Do you realize how many things are just plain wrong in this code? So bad, I wont even pretend to know what you are attempting to do.

Answer (score 0):

This part is wrong:

```
if(navigator.appName("Blackberry"))
```

appName is a string not a function, and that will probably cause your script to stop executing with an exception. Try

```
if (navigator.appName == "BlackBerry")
```

Note the second capital 'B'; from [the docs](http://us.blackberry.com/devjournals/resources/journals/mar_2007/bdjs.jsp)

> navigator.appName is set to the browser name, "BlackBerry".

You might want to make the comparison more lenient, e.g.

```
if (navigator.appName.toLowerCase().indexOf("blackberry") >= 0)
```

to look for 'BlackBerry' anywhere in the string, case insensitively. (For extra safety you could check navigator.appName is not null and is actually a string first, but that's probably not necessary.)